# reading data out of frequently updated excel sheet in python

Tags: python

I have been trying to get data out of an excel sheet. But the cell values are linked to some online database and it keeps changing every second or so. How can I read value of a particular cell without saving the sheet every time?

Comment: Can't you just use the links from the excel sheet to directly request the data contineously from the online database?

Comment: I don't have the direct link. The data is linked to the excel using some software. I just know that I will have some ever-changing data in an excel file and I need to do some operation if value in one of the cells hits some threshold

Comment: Can Macros be used for this? I mean for saving the workbook every 2 seconds or so?

Comment: Probably yes. [This SU-Post here sounds a lot like a similar issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1265717/excel-auto-save-macro)

Comment: Yeah that worked. Thanks anyways :)